# How do I remove a tag and add a class?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove the `<strong>` tag and add a class to every paragraph with a `<strong>` tag in it.

I need to be able to convert:

```
<p><strong>My ordinary sentence</strong></p>
```

To:

```
<p class="section-head">My ordinary sentence</p>
```

I have tried the following but it is missing some key ingredients

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.main > p > strong').parent().addClass('section-header');
    $('.main > p').innerHTML.replace(/<strong>/g, '');
    $('.main > p').innerHTML.replace(/<\/strong>/g, '');
   )};
</script>
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it as follow:

```js
$('p>strong').contents().unwrap().parent().addClass('section-head')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><strong>My ordinary sentence</strong></p>
<p>regular</p>
<p><strong>My ordinary sentence</strong></p>
<p>regular</p>
<p><strong>My ordinary sentence</strong></p>
```

This will keep the content of your paragraphs while removing the `<strong>` element.

`.contents().unwrap()` gets the content of the `<strong>` element and `.unwrap()` removes it. We then use `.parent()` to go back the DOM one level to the paragraph and add the `section-head` class to it.

The above code results in:

```
<p class="section-head">My ordinary sentence</p>
<p>regular</p>
<p class="section-head">My ordinary sentence</p>
<p>regular</p>
<p class="section-head">My ordinary sentence</p>
```

Comment: Brilliant - thank you for the speedy and effective response.